# How to get mount points name list?

Tags: java, kotlin, server, get, ntrip

I have ip and port, but I don't know name of mount point. How I can get it?

Then I want to connect to server:

```
GET /mountpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: some.ntrip.caster
Ntrip-Version: Ntrip/2.0
User-Agent: NTRIP client X/1.0
Connection: close
```

So, I need to know mount point name ...

Answer (score 1):

```
val socketAddress = InetSocketAddress(ip, port)
socket.connect(socketAddress, 10 * 1000)
```

...

```
if (socket.isConnected) {
  val request = ("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
    "User-Agent: NTRIP Client/1.0\r\n" +
    "Connection: close\r\n" +
    "\r\n").toByteArray()
  socket.getOutputStream().write(request)
  val response = String(socket.getInputStream().readBytes())
```

variable `response` contains mount points table